# how to do a global regex replacement in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a bunch of improperly generated Java classes, in which I need to correct variable naming pattern.
For example, where I encounter "duefromPsn" I need to have "duefrom_psn".
Basically, I need to find any occurrences of an upper case, and replace them with _ , as well as to change that upper case character to lower case.

Is there a way to do this type of global replacement in Sublime (or any other common text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press Ctrl-H. A new search-replace bar will open at the bottom of screen.
2. Press Alt-R to enable regular expression search replace.
3. Enter the regular expression in search and replace and hit enter.